# Connect guitar via XLR connector on Focusrite Scarlet Solo

Tags: xlr

Can I plug 2 guitars into a Focusrite Scarlett Solo, i.e. 1 into the regular instrument input and another using a converter to XLR like:
MainCore-6 35mm-Socket-Adapter-Converter

Is it possible and safe?
Is it dangerous to accidently use the 48v switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just stay safe & say 'no'.

Not only will the impedance be wrong & your guitar's output far too hot for a mic channel, sending phantom down the line to anything other than a mic can break things.

You could unbalance the cable by bridging cold to ground, but you're still facing the mismatch. It's not a cable I'd be happy to have floating round the studio, tbh.

Comment: What about a DI box? Maybe I didn't quite understand the question

Comment: @ToddWilcox - yeah, Di would work - https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/37856/connecting-electric-guitar-to-xlr?rq=1